# 'Rectangle' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Rectangle C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int height = 0;
            int width = 0;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black,2.5f);

```
        if (tabRemainder.SelectedTab == tabBank)
        {
            #region noBank
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray,new Rectangle(100,100,dataGridViewRemain.Columns[0].Width,dataGridViewRemain.Rows[0].Height));        
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen,new Rectangle(100,100,dataGridViewRemain.Columns[0].Width,dataGridViewRemain.Rows[0].Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridViewRemain.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString(),dataGridViewRemain.Font,Brushes.Black,new Rectangle(100,100,dataGridViewRemain.Columns[0].Width,dataGridViewRemain.Rows[0].Height));
            #endregion
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your full code I guess it seems that you were using both namespaces `System.Drawing` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. This caused ambiguity. Please replace `Rectangle` with the fully qualified name `System.Drawing.Rectangle`.